# How to generate a tet10 mesh from a tet4 mesh

Tags: finite-element, mesh-generation

I am writing a FEN solver on tet10 elements. I right now have a CFD grid gen tool (Pointwise) which generates tet4 meshes. From this I have the element connectivity list and the node list. How do I go about generating a tet10 mesh from this info.  Is there any particular tool/code to do this.

Comment: If you're not concerned about having curved boundaries, you can simply insert the new nodes at the midpoints of the tet4 points and update the connectivity accordingly. If you want it done for you, then the "Gmsh" package has the ability to output high-order elements, and they will respect the curves of the underlying geometry when they do so.